# Jetson Nano Numba GPU Vector Add benchmarking

Tags: python, numpy, gpu

I am trying to add of random vectors on GPU vs CPU using Numba vectorization.

Here is my example:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import vectorize

TARGET = 'cpu'
#TARGET = 'cuda'

@vectorize(["float64(float64, float64)"], target=TARGET)
def VectorAdd(a, b):
    return a + b

def main():
    N = 32_000_000

    A = np.random.randn(N)
    B = np.random.randn(N)
    C = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)

    print("Target unit: {}, number: {}".format(TARGET, N))
    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    vADD_time = timer() - start

    print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))

    print("Time: {}".format(vADD_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

CPU doing that in 30 times faster then CUDA. What I am doing wrong? Because I'd expect that CUDA must be faster.

```
Target unit: cuda, number: 32000000
C[:5] = [ 1.90362553 -2.6426849  -1.84243752 -0.00806387  0.63785922]
C[-5:] = [ 0.93794028  0.98118905  0.80945834  0.64350251 -1.62342203]
Time: 17.02285827000003

Target unit: cpu, number: 32000000
C[:5] = [ 0.77441334  0.35994057 -0.15359408 -0.20547891 -2.04108084]
C[-5:] = [1.47338646 3.01013048 0.71417303 1.62773266 2.80878941]
Time: 0.5268858470000168
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong other than  having unrealistic expectations of the performance of the GPU. Compiler driven parallelism is rarely anything other than mediocre. Yours is a good example of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you are performing is way too simple to fully exploit the parallelism the GPU provides; instead you are only losing the performance from the memory transfer overhead.

Try running the following code, which doesn't measure the time spent on data transfer by manually moving them.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from numba import (vectorize, cuda)

# TARGET = 'cpu'
TARGET = 'cuda'


@vectorize(["float64(float64, float64)"], target=TARGET)
def VectorAdd(a, b):
    return a + b


def main():
    N = 32_000_000
    A = np.random.randn(N)
    B = np.random.randn(N)
    C = np.zeros(N, dtype=np.float64)

    A = cuda.to_device(A)
    B = cuda.to_device(B)

    print("Target unit: {}, number: {}".format(TARGET, N))
    start = timer()
    C = VectorAdd(A, B)
    vADD_time = timer() - start
    C = C.copy_to_host()
    print("C[:5] = " + str(C[:5]))
    print("C[-5:] = " + str(C[-5:]))
    print("Time: {}".format(vADD_time))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Also, I would suggest increasing the number of iteration you perform to see the speedup from GPU.

Comment: That will help a bit, but only a bit. I doubt that there is any usage case for numba.vectorize that will be faster on Jetson class GPU than its CPU

Comment: Yeah, this fix increase evaluation speed.
CUDA Time: 6.317502703000002 
CPU Time: 0.612331557999994
I had try to set N=64_000_000 but my jetson got stucked.